# Multidimensional array in Android from SQLite

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

Could anyone please explain how I can achieve the same from SQLite query in Java? The following is the code:

```
static final String[] AUTHORS = new String[] { "Roberto Bola–o","David Mitchell"};

private static final String[][] BOOKS = 
              new String[][] { "The Savage Detectives", "2666" },{ "Ghostwritten",
                                "number9dream", "Cloud Atlas","Black Swan Green", 
                                         "The Thousand Autumns of Jacob de Zoet" } };
```

This code is from the following class to implement sectioned gridview:[Sectioned Gridview](https://github.com/velos/SectionedGrid/blob/master/src/com/velosmobile/demo/BookcaseAdapter.java)

Comment: You wouldn't.  You could get the data from SQLite and put it into that type of a data structure.  But how you'd do that would depend on what your schema is like.  And if you don't have one of those yet, the best schema depends on what you want to do in your app.

Comment: Thank you, I have a students table  with  the following schema: [_id, studentName, Teacher] I want to display students per teacher.